# Sequelize Bulk Insert with hasOne association.

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize to bulk insert data into two tables which have one-to-one association with each other.
But I am having a problem with bulkInsert because bulk insert doesn't return anything. As stated in the docs:

```
User.bulkCreate([
  { username: 'barfooz', isAdmin: true },
  { username: 'foo', isAdmin: true },
  { username: 'bar', isAdmin: false }
]).then(function() { // Notice: There are no arguments here, as of right now you'll have to...
  return User.findAll();
}).then(function(users) {
  console.log(users) // ... in order to get the array of user objects
})
```

I have a UserDetail table, how can I add User.hasOne(UserDetail) mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define it in your userDetail model defintion

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var UserDetail = sequelize.define("user_detail", {
    //insert fields here
  });
  UserDetail.belongsTo(models.User, {
   foreignKey: {
     allowNull: false
   }
  });
  return UserDetail;
};
```

Make sure you have a foreign key in the User model defintion